# Remapping arguments of topics

Tags: ros, remapping, topic, remap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all:

I have a question about remapping topics in launch files. I have a controller which is subscribed to the topics: `/pelican/pose` and `/pelican/twist`, expecting a `Pose` and a `Twist` respectively. Gazebo publishes both information in the topic `/gazebo/model_states`, so I expected do do the following remappings:

`/gazebo/model_states/pose[1]` to `/pelican/pose`

`/gazebo/model_states/twist[1]` to `/pelican/twist`

Doing the remap of `/gazebo/model_states` works well, but the ones before do not work. Anyone knows how can I do that, or something similar?

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214390/remapping-arguments-of-topics/) by [AdrianGonzalez](https://answers.ros.org/users/12721/adriangonzalez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2015-07-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2015-07-23**:
Could you post your launch-file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are trying to remap the content of the message not the topic, which you can't do directly.

You'll need to write a simple node that subscribes to `gazebo/model_states` and publishes the desired topics.

<strike>Another option, if you don't want to write the simple node, would be to try to use the [topic-tools/transform](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/transform) node.</strike>

Edit: this also won't work...

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2015-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1